# Show snack bar to handling missing URL receivers

Tags: flutter, dart

I used the [url_luncher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) package and it suggests handle the missing URL receiver in case of target platform can not handle the URL.
So I create a function to handle of onTap of CardTile widget and dial the phone number and if the target platform can not handle the request it shows a snake bar to inform the user in UI.
But I have two problems 1) if using an anonymous function I get a runtime error and my code would be wordly and long

```
Unhandled Exception: No ScaffoldMessenger widget found.
MyApp widgets require a ScaffoldMessenger widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a ScaffoldMessenger ancestor was:
MyApp
The ancestors of this widget were:
[root]
Typically, the ScaffoldMessenger widget is introduced by the MaterialApp at the top of your application widget tree.
```

2. if use function name onTap of CardTile widget for example `onTap : _urlLauncherFunction(context)` I can not pass BuildContext context argument to the function and get a compile error

`This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.`

I could not figure out what did wrong so please guide and help me to solve this.
I paste the anonymous function version here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
final telLaunchErrorSnackBar = SnackBar(
    content:
    Text('Your device can not handle this url'));
final String _myPhoneNumber = '+9812345678';
//use xml scheme to trigger error otherwise it should be tel
final Uri _telUri = Uri(scheme: 'xml', path: _myPhoneNumber);
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/image.jpg'),
              ),
              Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.phone,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    '00 123 45657',
                  ),
                  onTap: () async {
                    String telUri = _telUri.toString();
                    await canLaunch(telUri)
                        ? await launch(telUri)
                        : ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                        .showSnackBar(telLaunchErrorSnackBar);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I code as this , flutter throw a error.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      // home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              onTap: (){
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('content')));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

then I change

```
...
MaterialApp(
  home:Scafford(...),
)
...
```

to

```
...
MaterialApp(
  home:Home(),
)
...
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Scaffold(...);
  }
}
```

It works.